# Why are my jQuery Promises being ignored when calling JSOM executeQueryAsync?

Tags: jquery, sharepoint-2013

I'm scratching my head over a little issue I have with jQuery Promises. Basically I am trying to chain several method calls (held within a plugin) so that they are called in sequence.

However because one of the functions has an SP context.executeQueryAsync call, when I try this, they seem to get called with the final method not waiting for the resolved state of the promise before proceeding.

I have replicated something similar to what i am doing using timeouts, in the following jsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/qPHmu/11/

Here is a basic version from the method using the executeQueryAsync call:

```
GetList: function (listTitle, fields, camlXml) {
                var dfd = new $.Deferred();
                $this = $(this);

                var data = $this.data('SPLists');

                if (!data) {
                    var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle);
                    var query = new SP.CamlQuery(camlXml);
                    var items = list.getItems(query);

                    context.load(items, 'Include (' + fields + ')');
                    context.executeQueryAsync(function () {
                        dfd.resolve();
                    },
                    function (sender, args) {
                        dfd.reject();
                    });
                }

                return dfd.promise();
        }
```

I am calling my functions in the same way as in the jsfiddle example. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The following wont wait with executing the MyPromiseTest function:

```
$.fn.MyPromiseTest()
    .done($.fn.MyPromiseTest("Get"))
        .done($.fn.MyPromiseTest("Final"));
```

Try it [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/qPHmu/12/):

```
$.fn.MyPromiseTest()
    .done(function() { 
        return $.fn.MyPromiseTest("Get").done(function() { 
            return $.fn.MyPromiseTest("Final"); 
        })
    });
```

**EDIT:**

You can also use [.pipe](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.pipe/) to update the promise (as of 1.8 you should use [.then](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/)):

```
$.fn.MyPromiseTest()
    .pipe(function() { return $.fn.MyPromiseTest("Get"); })
    .pipe(function() { return $.fn.MyPromiseTest("Final"); });
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/qPHmu/13/

Comment: Hi, thanks for your quick answer!

This works for the timeout JsFiddle example but not for async calls outside of jQuery (SharePoint 2013 executeQueryAsync). Any ideas?